# Problems install Ubuntu 18.10 server

Tags: boot, server, uefi

I haven't been able to find a solution to this problem. I'm trying to install Ubuntu server on an old HP 6200 SFF PC. If I use the desktop install image on a USB stick, created in windows using Rufus, and select full disk install, all goes well and the install completes and all is good.
This is the file ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso

BUT.... I don't want to install a desktop version, I want to install just a server version. If I try the server install it fails at step 10/11 when efibootmgr cannot set a boot device order. I have tried both the 18.04 and 18.10 versions.
This is the file file (I also tried 18.04 versions) ubuntu-18.10-live-server-amd64.iso

Then I thought I'd try the alternative install (ubuntu-18.10-server-amd64.iso) but it was worse. As soon as I get to the select a language screen (the second one, after start install) the install program refuses to recognize my USB keyboard. I even switched slots.

So i'm stuck. I can install the desktop version, which I don't want, or I'll have to look for another distro.

I have tried booting to a non-UEFI device to no avail. My BIOS interface has no setting to disable UEFI so those possibilities are off the table.

Can someone suggest a working server install or give me the list of apt-get removes and installs I can apply to the desktop version that will give me a server version?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *If I try the server install it fails at step 10/11 when efibootmgr cannot set a boot device order* - did you got any error messages? How do you know it failed to set a boot device order?

Comment: Also, have you tried to set legacy mode for USB controller in BIOS in case of alternative 18.10-server install?

Comment: Q1. Yes I get a message that shows the entire command. alas as the install fails and never says where the log is I have not been able to copy it. Once, I exited to the terminal and retried the command and got the same error. 

Q2 yes I tried that and it made no difference.